# Motion (Newtonian Mechanics)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

When a net force is applied to an object and the object starts to accelerate, will its motion with this acceleration continue endlessly?( no other forces opposing this motion)
If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration of an object at any point in time is equal to the net force being exerted on it divided by its mass.  The acceleration will continue as long as the force is being applied.